# jQuery Mobile setting Icons for Buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am trying to add icons to buttons, which I have dynamically created using jQuery. I created the css class for the button. On running, I am getting a grey round circle on the side of the button, instead of the image. On inspecting elements, I get that the image for the button has been overridden.

How do I ensure that button icons appear instead of the grey circle?
The Code I have used is:

JS:

```
var btn1 = $("<button/>", {'id': 'TestButton'}).html('Sample Button');
btn1.buttonMarkup({ theme: 'c', icon: 'btn1' });
```

CSS:

```
.ui-icon-btn1 {
    background-image: url('../../images/gallery.jpg');
    background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
    border-style: hidden;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is that you put `!important` to that property.

```
background: url('../../images/gallery.jpg') !important;
background-color: rgb(255,255,255) !important;
```

This worked for me on similar issue with jQuery- mobile.

**Edit:**

To remove the Disc around the button, you need to add

```
`border: 0 !important;`
```

to the class

`.ui-li-link-alt .ui-btn` but make sure you do not override the default behavior of the **jQuery UI**.

Comment: Got the image. Thanks for that
I am still getting the grey round disc  though. How can I remove that?

Comment: I am trying something like this
.ui-li-link-alt .ui-btn {
    border: 0 !important;
}
Is this what you meant?

Comment: Yes, thats what you need to do to remove the default border.